# How to debug an Outlook add-in?

Tags: javascript, outlook, office-js, add-in

I recently made an Office add-in for Outlook, using Yeoman generator. The add-in is a taskpane that can be opened when writing an email and allow the user to insert an HTML object inside the mail's body. It seemed to be working as expected when running in a web browser, but got bugs reports with the Outlook application, so I now have to debug my add-in running outside of a browser environment.

First thing is : how do I install the add-in when using Outlook? I tried to do the same procedure as on browser, with `npm run dev-server` and loading the manifest, but the add-in disappears from the list as soon as I close the add-ins window, so I assume I'm missing a step.

I've also tried to side-load my project with `npm start`, but even if the web-server and Outlook are correctly launched, the add-in taskpane doesn't appear.

Does anyone know how you're supposed to launch an Outlook add-in inside Outlook application?

Comment: Hi you can follow this link - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/test-debug-office-add-ins

Answer (score 0):

It's been a few weeks since I post, I totally forgot to answer.

I already had read the Add-ins documentation and none of its solutions seemed to work.

Another member of my team took a look of this problem and managed to solve it by modifying the manifest.xml file. We couldn't exactly find out what part of it was causing the issue, but he swapped a part with a previous manifest and the add-in start working again.

So, if anyone meets the same issue, you should take a look at your manifest.